# Is it possible to repair damaged win 11 registry(won't start) by creating new same version windows 11 on Virtual Machine and copying that registry

Tags: windows, boot, windows-registry

I got error message on win 11 "The operating system could not be loaded because the system registry file is missing or contains errors."

File ... system32/config/system

What I tried:

- System troubleshooter wont work.
- SFC /Scannow won't work, start. Tried many things won't work.
- DISM won't work again.
- I did not make system restore.
- I think there is no spare registry file as I saw the data.
- Bootrec /Fixboot (Access Is Denied.) That did not work as well.

I don't know what to try. I got an idea that I can try to make windows in Linux vm machine and copy that registry file(what precisely do I need to copy?) into non working one to fix it. Could that fix it and would I keep installed programs?

I don't know is is possible to reinstall win 11 on top of damaged old win 11 to keep the apps working?

I put a lot of work into that and try to save it. I would be thankful for any help, what could I try! Drive is new SSD, so I doubt it is the drive issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your VM Windows 11 will have a very different registry than the older Windows 11 system.

The idea to use a very different registry on your older system will likely not work.

You may be to able replace specific broken keys but that might be too difficult to do.

Short answer:  Using a different registry will not likely work (greater than 95%).

Windows 11 (troubled system) will not start, so Repair Install will not work.

Best to reinstall Windows 11 on the troubled system.

Boot with a bootable USB Key to recover what documents you need.